# Crontab issue, even when I have the file in the directory is says "No such file or directory"

Tags: python, cron

Even when I have the file in the directory is says "No such file or directory" How do I fix this?

I'm using `crontab -e` to add tho crontab.

Crontab;

```
MAILTO="" 
*/1 * * * * /home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py 2>/tmp/twitterBot.log
```

Bot.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from TwitterFollowBot import TwitterBot
my_bot = TwitterBot()

from TwitterFollowBot import TwitterBot
my_bot = TwitterBot("config.txt")  

from TwitterFollowBot import TwitterBot   
my_bot = TwitterBot()
my_bot.sync_follows()

from TwitterFollowBot import TwitterBot    
my_bot = TwitterBot()
my_bot.auto_rt("@ShoutGamers", count=2200)
```

Path;

```
/home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py
```

Crontab log;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py", line 5, in <module>
    my_bot = TwitterBot()
  File "/home/TwitterFollowBot/TwitterFollowBot/__init__.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.bot_setup(config_file)
  File "/home/TwitterFollowBot/TwitterFollowBot/__init__.py", line 78, in bot_setup
    with open(config_file, "r") as in_file:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config.txt'
```

Comment: What is **the** directory? The directory from which cron starts your program ( `/` )?

Answer (score 0):

Crontab doesn't run your code in the directory its in, as it just runs the command you've put in from whatever location its configured to (probably your home directory).

You can solve that by getting the path of your file via `sys.argv`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os.path
from TwitterFollowBot import TwitterBot

path = sys.argv[0].rsplit("/", 1)[0]

TwitterBot()  # I don't know if this does something, but as the assigned value is never used...

TwitterBot(os.path.join(path, "config.txt"))  # Same here. I put the path in front of "config.txt"

TwitterBot().sync_follows()

TwitterBot().auto_rt("@ShoutGamers", count=2200)
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help but where do I need to put this coding part?

Comment: Still not working, do you thin it'll work if I ignore" my_bot.auto_rt" and put it as " .auto_rt "

Comment: @IsuruNuwanSubasinghe Can you send me the error message you are getting now?

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me, I manged to solve my issue here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/853764/crontab-is-not-running-properly-with-py